# Silverlight Navigation Framework with Unity Container

Tags: silverlight, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm using the Silverlight Navigation Framework and have recently been coding my appliation in the following general way:

```
Public MasterPageView: UserControl
{
    private IMasterPageViewModel _ViewModel = null;

    public MasterPageView():this(new MasterPageViewModel(), new BusinessObjectProvider())
    {
    }

    public MasterPage(IMasterPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _ViewModel = viewModel;
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Now that i have the skeleton of my project created, i want to carry out some tidying up, before the heavy development starts.  As part of my refactoring process i want to make use of the Unity IOC and take out my Default constructors.

Has anybody used the Silverlight Navigation Framework with Unity?  I would appreciate any suggestions on how to go about this.

The Main Problems and questions i see are
1) Where do i register the Objects in the Unity Framework?
2) All Views are created using the URIMAPPER in the Silverlight Navigation Framework, how do we get the URIMAPPER to use Unity to create its Views.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can help I think. I'm constantly confused on which parts of this "stuff" is considered "Unity" and what is "Prism". Are you using stuff like "bootstrappers", "regions", and "modules" (I think this was part of Prism)? This is where adding navigation got complicated.

Comment: Yes that is Prism. Unity is the IOC Container that comes with Prism, that is the UnityContainer Class.  I have a Silverlight Navigation site, the problem is When Navigating to a new Page, the URIMapper creates the View to navigate to.  What i think i need for starters is a way for the URIMapper to call into the IOC Container to resolve the View

Comment: OK, I just let the navigation system make the view the way it wants. I use IOC-aware XAML controls (Prism regions) in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.davidpoll.com/2009/11/30/opening-up-silverlight-4-navigation-introduction-to-inavigationcontentloader/

Answer (score 0):

We use Prism Regions in the XAML of each Page. The regions will automagically do the IOC stuff when it creates the view registered to it. So the Pages don't get created via Unity, but the Regions they contain do.

About all the code in the Pages do is communicate any Url parameters to the Regions. This is a somewhat ugly thing done by the pages; they stuff querystring parmas into the Region's RegionContext param. The View of the region then has some code in it to get that context data and pass it to its Unity provided VM.

If you're not using Prism this won't help much. EDIT: There was some more details on getting Prism regions to work well with navigation Pages. I'll share if you want to go this route.

We do, at times, access the unity container via a static method we created (I think that static method just Resolves objects for you, it doesn't give everyone the entire container interface). It sucks, but you can resolve things manually with that.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing people create views by passing them through an IOC container always makes me feel dirty.  Your design surfaces (Visual Studio and Expression Blend) won't do this -- they insist on a default constructor.  So why fight them?

A much cleaner solution is to use the view model locator pattern.  Here's a basic one:

```
public abstract class ViewModelLocator<TViewModel>
{
  public TViewModel ViewModel
  {
    get { return StaticGateway.ServiceLocator.GetInstance<TRuntimeViewModel>(); }
  }
}
```

Where StaticGateway is a static class that provides access to your unity container and exposes it's ServiceLocator.  Then you simply declare one:

```
public class MasterPageViewModelLocator : ViewModelLocator<IMasterPageViewModel> { }
```

And use it in XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourCompany.MasterPageView"  etc.>

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MasterPageViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="ViewModel" />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  ...etc...
</UserControl>
```

Your bindings will generally be much happier because you're setting a data context in your XAML.  Setting the data context in code behind can lead to some weird behaviors particularly when you get to interesting thinks like attached behaviors.  And you're still totally using your IOC container to perform dependency injection with the added benefit of all your design surfaces continue to function.

As for where to register, I'm not sure exactly where you'd put that in a Navigation app.  Typically you use Unity with something like Prism and perform the registration in the module initializers.  I suppose you could do it in your App class or come up with an equivalent to the module initializer (but then you should just use Prism rather than reinventing the wheel).

Comment: In my current design I now have a default Constructor for all of my Views. Inside the Default Constructor body i have a this.DataContext = MyViewModelProvider.Resolve<MasterViewModel>();  Do you think this is a bad idea and need reworking.  Seems to be testable and is only one line of code in the View

Comment: I think it can be a bad idea, depending on the particulars of your situation.  Worse, it might be okay now, but not okay later after you make further enhancements.  That's why I always just start with a view model locator in XAML.  And it may be "only one line code", but it's a very important line of code that makes everything go.  Here's an experiment: open up your view in Blend and see how it looks now.  If you're satisfied, then move on.  If you're not satisfied, try what I suggested and you'll see an improvement.